# What is this in table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In Phone app, in contacts tab on tab bar, there is things in table view.

These are between contact cells and bright gray, and have a little transparent effect and a alphabet character on it. They are separating by alphabet group.

I think they are a kind of table view cell and want to know how to use it. (name or sample code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, they are called table header views, and you add them by implementing

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in your table view data source.

Comment: Thank you. you were correct. I misunderstood the method is activated in UITableViewStyleGrouped only.

Answer (score 0):

These are indeed headers for the tableView, but unlike the above comment suggests, you don't need to have a grouped table view style in order to provide headers. If you examine the Apple documentation for the Table View Programming Guide, there is a section for setting up an indexed table view. Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Check out the section Populating an Indexed List.

Comment: If this answers your question, please upvote the answer and mark it as such so that other people coming here know this answered your question. Thanks.